Can Advanced Oxidative Processes (AOPs) destroy nitrates and phosphates?
I am currently working on a science project about treating agricultural wastewater and the subsequent eutrophication that occurs.
I was wondering if Advanced Oxidative Processes (AOPs) could destroy nitrates and phosphates, particularly if hydroxyl radicals could react and neutralize these phosphates and nitrates due to their high reactivity. Specifically, I've been working on the electro-Fenton process to degrade dyes, and was wondering if that same method could be used to degrade these agricultural chemicals.
Thanks!

In short, no.
Advanced Oxidative Processes (AOPs) such as electro-Fenton process oxidize organic chemicals. "The electro-Fenton technology is an advanced oxidation process that is efficient for the degradation of organic pollutants." Phosphates (containing $\ce{PO4^-^3}$) and nitrates (containing $\ce{NO3-}$) are already oxidized. It would be like selling coals to Newcastle -- they have all the oxygen they need, thank you very much.
The electro-Fenton process has another great disadvantage: "it suffers from the high operating costs due to the need for power investment." Nitrates and phosphates are used in huge amounts. In statistics for 2021, about 100,000,000 metric tonnes (1014 grams) of nitrates (and other nitrogen compounds, e.g., urea) and about 50,000,000 metric tonnes (5 x 1013 grams) of phosphates were used in agriculture. Even if the electro-Fenton process were able to ameliorate the runoff of these contaminants, it would be economically unfeasible.
